# How to send array values from view to controller in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to send array of values from view to controller, I have a option of submitting the form with hidden fields but i don want to view my hidden fields value by fire bug or view source code

Any other options will be helpful for me

Comment: You can't hide™ hidden fields from view-source. It is meant to be hidden from html preview or better said to be hidden from reader/visitor. Check [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html). What is your intention, explain more what do you try to achive.

Comment: I need to send some array values from view to controller that should not be viewed through view page source or firebug

Comment: What values? Explain it more. Read [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) of how to ask and post relevant code you made so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
If i got it clearly. you can use session set_userdata()  
View:-
$data = array(  
        'a'  => 'some value',  
        'b'  => 'another value'  
);  
$this->session->set_userdata($data);

Controller:-

$a = $this->session->userdata('a');  
$b = $this->session->userdata('b');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from view to controller I suppose that you data is coming from form, like

view.php

```
<?= form_open('test_form/test_post', '', array('hidden_1' => 'value1', 'hidden_2', 'value_2'))?>
    <?= form_hidden('hidden_3', 'value3');?>
    <?= form_input('username', 'default_value');?><br>
    <?= form_input('phone', '555-555');?><br>
    <?= form_submit('submit', 'Send');?>
<?= form_close();?>
```

controller test_form.php

```
public function test_form(){
    $hidden1    = $this->input->post('hidden_1', TRUE);
    $hidden2    = $this->input->post('hidden_2', TRUE);
    $hidden3    = $this->input->post('hidden_3', TRUE);
    $username   = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
    $phone      = $this->input->post('phone', TRUE);

    echo "1 - $hidden1<br>2 - $hidden2<br>3 - $username<br>4 - $phone";
}
```

Or you can change the name of every input to a variable in a array like
view.php

```
<?= form_hidden($values[], 'value3');?>
<?= form_input($values[], 'default_value');?><br>
<?= form_input($values[], '555-555');?><br>
```

and in your ocntroller make a var_dump post